# How to run different async function in same thread?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, async-await, threadpool

There are 2 async function. I want to make second async function run in the thread of first async function in java

Comment: Then it isn't async...

Comment: Yes, the async function will be in a different thread from main, but if this function is called again in the same session, I want it to execute in the same thread as the first call. Is it possible?

Comment: That is not what you described and no that is not possible afaik. Why would it need to run in the same thread in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single threaded executor (service):

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
try {
    // call submit / execute for the first task
    // call submit / execute for the second task
} finally {
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

An alternative is to use `CompletableFuture`:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> firstTask())
        .thenApply(resultOfFirstTask -> runSecondTask(resultOfFirstTask))
        // do other stuff with the CompletableFuture
```

This uses a function that takes the result of the first task and uses it as input for the second task. If the first task doesn't return anything, you can use `runAsync` instead of `supplyAsync`. If the second task doesn't return anything, you can use `thenAccept` instead of `thenApply`. And/or if the second task doesn't use the input of the first task, just ignore the result of the first task:

```
        .thenApply(ignored -> runSecondTask())
        // or .thenRun(() -> runSecondTask()) instead of thenAccept
```

There are other methods besides `thenApply` and `thenAccept`, just make sure to use the right one. As far as I could tell, the ones you'd need all start with `then` and don't take another `CompletableFuture` / `CompletionStage`.